# Conditional signing config and build type?

Tags: android, gradle

Is it possible to create a signing config and a build type only if a certain expression is true?  For example I only want to create a XYZ config and type if a certain environment variable is present (checking the environment variable with `hasProperty('envVar')`).

Comment: Since Gradle is based on Groovy, you certainly have full access to conditional expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, by simply coding a [groovy if](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Logical+Branching) directly into your build:

```
signingConfigs { 
    // Standard configs ...

    if (project.hasProperty("specialRelease")){
        specialRelease { 
            //Config properties
        }
    }
}  

//..

buildTypes {
    //Standard types...

    if (project.hasProperty("specialRelease")){
        specialRelease { 
            signingConfig signingConfigs.playStoreRelease
            //Other build properties...
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind you have to use `project.hasProperty` per [Gradle issue 1826](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1826).